# How can I cancel these downloads from the Windows 10 Store?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I have these downloads that I don't know where I got: **Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML** and **Microsoft .Net Native Framework Package 1.0**

I can't cancel it even when I reset the store from **wsreset**. I even deleted the folders from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

Anyone getting this problem as well?

[image]

Comment: that are SDKs from Microsoft that 3rd party developers use in their apps. Simply install them

Comment: @magicandre1981 Well, can I install them manually? I can't rely on the downloads queue due to it being stuck.

Comment: look if there is a file called **winstore.log** in Win10. If yes, Open it and look for errors.